# Inserting related entity ids over rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working with api built by another company. They created insert endpoint expecting POST payload like this:

```
{
   name: 'a',
   surname: 'b',
   relatedBoards: [
       {
            id: '123'
       },
       {
            id: '34'
       },
   ] 
}
```

Where this feels way unneeded and I'd expect to make post with following payload:

```
{
   name: 'a',
   surname: 'b',
   relatedBoards: ['123', '34']
}
```

I don't know python or django rest myself, but this feels like a lot of needed mapping before making the request. 
Is this true that `Django rest framework` expects payload like this and it can't be changed?

Is there a reason for this data structure?

I have never seen it like this. What is your experience?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that kind of structure comes directly from Django restframework's requirements. You can create serializers and mapping is restframework supporting list of strings. If I had to guess, I would say they are preparing the relatedBoards to have more properties later (than just the id). Or they have been lazy in the mapping of their model to the API.

Now, depending how they have implemented the serializers in the API that one string presentation *might* map to the model that is behind relatedBoards and you could make that kind of call. Still, you should stick to the API presented or ask them to make it more sound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have a similar opinion to yours. If I may ask - which structure of the two would you expect to use?  This is if there is no more additional requirements. Which there aren't - I checked

Comment: Which structure do I think _should_ be used or which structure I think they are using? I would opt with the list of strings (or integers, actually). They probably have in the backend some kind of database models etc. where the id is needed for.